# Visual Studios 2010 C++ how to view all instantiated classes at a breakpoint.

Tags: c++, visual-studio, visual-studio-2010, stack, trace

I have to work on some old code that has to use VS 2010. Furthermore, there’s no documentation to this code. Is there a way at a breakpoint in VS to view all the threads that have been created and all the classes that have been instantiated under each thread?

Comment: In VS 2010 debugging mode, the left-most of the two panes on the bottom has a Threads tab you should find useful. Unfortunately objects are not associated with the thread under which they were created, so figuring out which objects belong to which threads might be tricky. Automatics should be on their thread's stack, but all bets are off for dynamic objects.

Comment: Thank you very for the information.  This gave me enough information to figure out what I needed.

Comment: Can I mark that as the answer?

Comment: No. That's just a comment. I didn't know if there would be enough  information to make a useful answer. Still don't think there is enough there to be useful to a future asker.  You know what you did to solve the problem. If you think someone in the future can learn from it, I recommend that you write up what you did and self answer.